# C# winform application security Vulnerability Testing Tools

Tags: winforms, security, testing, c#-4.0

Does anyone have any recommendations for good vulnerability testing software for c# window forms (not .net) applications.

Preferably one that can also test with a mysql server or sql server connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool that is going to match a good code reviewer or penetration tester.  But a few tips to get you aimed in the right direction:

- Static analysis tools like HP Fortify, IBM AppScan, and CheckMarx do a wonderful job at finding security issues with code.  But you really need an experienced code reviewer to get the most out of them.  Also, they are not cheap!  These tools operate by scanning code, and the main requirement is to provide to the tool everything you need to build your software (at least this is the case for Fortify and AppScan, not sure if the same requirement holds for CheckMarx).
- IAST tools such as Contrast are also not cheap.  However at least in the case of Contrast, they are specifically trying to make it more developer-friendly.  IAST tools work by hooking into your binary in your test environment and looking under the hood for bad things that happen.
- Dynamic analysis tools such as OWASP ZAP (free) and Burp (not free, but affordable) can run automated scans in your environment, but if you lack experience with these, then your value is limited.  These tools work by scanning in a test environment and sending malicious payloads to see how the server responds.  A lot of effort is being put to make ZAP work in continuous integration build environments.

All of these should work for the technologies that you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the exact answer I was looking for.